# cannot fetch the remote branch nor switch to that

Tags: git

I am on master branch trying to switch to remot branch

```
git checkout origin/myNewBranch
```

doesn't work nor this one:

```
git checkout myNewBranch
```

I already fetched the remote branches in the past and if I do `git branch -a` , I will see a list of them but I have a modified file, when I do `git status` I will get the modified file:

```
modified:   skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf
```

therefore I cannot switch.

then I tried so many solutions to **redo the change**, I did not even change this file, it is comming when i checked out the repository, I did this:

```
git stash
git stash pop
```

did not work, so I did this:

```
git checkout --
```

did not work, so I did this:

```
git checkout -- skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf
```

did not work, I did this:

```
gir rebase master
```

did not work, I did these:

```
 git add --all
```

then

```
git fetch --all
```

then

```
git reset --hard skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
        lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf
```

did not work as well.

`git checkout --force master` says already on master.

git status output:

```
c:\wamp\www\magentodev>git status

    On branch master
    Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

            modified:   skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/Helvetica-Neue-
    LT-Com-67-Medium-Condensed.ttf

    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I also did this:

```
git checkout skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf
```

still the modified file is there.

Comment: can you post full output of git status?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: git checkout skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf. The change is removed from working directory. I can change to another branch.

Comment: I did but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the file
`rm -f skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf`

And get the original file back:
`git checkout skin/frontend/enterprise/scosche/walmart/css/helvetica-neue-
lt-com-67-medium-condensed.ttf`

Comment: I did but when I do git status it tells me the same thing modified is still this file.

Comment: my bad I did remove it

Comment: when I removed the file it is not there anymore to check it out :)) what should I do

Comment: I did the stash and I have the file again but I cannot check it out as you said

Comment: ok I removed the file completely and instead of checking out the path I just ran checkout and surprisingly this one worked.